# reference variable in object literal?

Tags: javascript, object-literal

say I have

```
myfunc({
  var1: 1,
  var2: 2,
})
```

if i want to have a value that makes use of the current unnamed object, how would I do this?

eg if I wanted

```
myfunc({
  var1: 1,
  var2: 2,
  var3: this.var1 + this.var2
})
```

obviously this does not work.

What would the correct syntax be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, that isn't possible. While an object literal is being constructed, no external reference to that object exists until the entire literal is evaluated. The only way to use `this` at this stage is to use a constructor instead:

```
function MyObject() {
  this.var1 = 1;
  this.var2 = 2;
  this.var3 = this.var1 + this.var2;
}

myfunc(new MyObject());
```

Answer (score 20):

You could make var3 a function, and calling it will allow you to use 'this':

```
x= {
    v1:4,
    v2:5,
    v3:function(){return this.v1 + this.v2;}
};

alert(x.v3());
```

Comment: Exactly what the OP wanted I think.

Comment: The problem is that syntax is different x.v1 and x.v3().

Comment: If you want the same syntax you can change v1 and v2 to be functions as well

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it in the notation you're using. An object literal doesn't have any notion of itself in this context.