# Reference nested 'sibling'-property in object literal

Tags: javascript, object-literal

I want to reference a nested property in an object literal from within another property in that same object literal.

Consider the following contrived example:

```
var obj = {
   product1: {
      price: 80,
      price_was: 100,
      discount: function(){

        return 100 - (100 * (price/price_was));

        //I don't want to use:  
        //100 - (100 * (this.product1.price/this.product1.price_was))
        //because the name of the parent ('product1' in this case) isn't known 
        //a-priori.

      }
   }
}
```

The above is obviously incorrect, but how to get to 'price' and 'price_was' from within 'discount'?

I've looked at the following question, which is close, but in that question the needed property is a direct child of 'this', which in the above example isn't the case.
[reference variable in object literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858931/reference-variable-in-object-literal)

Any way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Self-references in object literal declarations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literal-declarations)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *"...in that question the needed property is a direct child of 'this', which in the above example isn't the case"*

Actually, it probably is if you're calling `.discount()` from the `productN` object.

So you wouldn't use `this.product1.price`, because if you're calling `discount` from `productN`, then `this` will be a reference to `productN`.

Just do this:

```
this.price;
this.price_was;
```

...so it would look like:

```
var obj = {
   product1: {
      price: 80,
      price_was: 100,
      discount: function(){

        return 100 - (100 * (this.price/this.price_was));

      }
   }
};
```

Again, this assumes you're calling the function from the `productN` object. If not, it would be helpful if you would show *how* `discount` is being called.

Comment: That makes sense. So 'this' shifts depending on where on the object-literal you're calling from. Good to know! I will check first thing tomorrow. (I was designing on paper, when this thing popped up).  BTW: how do you format 'inline code' like you did in your answer?

Comment: @Geert-Jan: Yes, but there are actually about a half-dozen ways that `this` can be set, but in the form of `obj.method()`, `this` will be set to the `obj`. The inline formatting is achieved by wrapping the \`  grave accent symbol around the text. Or just select the text, and click the **`{ }`** code button at the top of the edit area, and it will wrap it for you.