# How do I access something in its own object?

Tags: javascript

If I wanted to access a value within itself (an object), how would I go about doing so?

Here's what I have (simplified):

```
options = {
    'image' : {
        'height' : {
        'upper' : 100,
        'lower' : 25
        },
        'width'  : {
        'upper' : 100,
        'lower' : 25
        },
    'dimensions' : (Math.floor(Math.random() * (options.image.height.upper - options.image.height.lower) + options.image.height.lower)) + 'x' +                                                         (Math.floor(Math.random() * (options.image.width.upper - options.image.width.lower) + options.image.width.lower())),
        'color' : 'fff'
};
```

If you look at options.dimensions, I'm attempting to access the values in height and width, yet I believe my scope is wrong.

Is there a way to access what I need the way I'm doing it? If not, what's a better way to go about this?

Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry in advance for the poor formatting.

Comment: Does `this.image.height` work?

Comment: `this` will not work, since it points to the method's scope

Comment: Possibly a better example: [How to reference a key from the same object when creating it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396518/how-to-reference-a-key-from-the-same-object-when-creating-it?lq=1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it in two steps:

```
options = {
    'image' : {
        'height' : {
            'upper' : 100,
            'lower' : 25
        },
        'width'  : {
            'upper' : 100,
            'lower' : 25
        },
        'color' : 'fff'
    }
};

options.dimensions = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 
    (options.image.height.upper - options.image.height.lower) + options.image.height.lower)) + 
    'x' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * (options.image.width.upper - options.image.width.lower) +
    options.image.width.lower()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try

```
options = {
    'image' : {
        'height' : {
        'upper' : 100,
        'lower' : 25
        },
        'width'  : {
        'upper' : 100,
        'lower' : 25
        },
        'color' : 'fff'
};

options['dimensions'] = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (options.image.height.upper - options.image.height.lower) + options.image.height.lower)) + 'x' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * (options.image.width.upper - options.image.width.lower) + options.image.width.lower()));
```

I don't think there any way to refer an object which still not created.