# Reference variable in definition?

Tags: javascript

How can I reference variable while define it in Javascript?

```
var person = {
 basic: {
   name: 'jack',
   sex: 0,
 },
 profile: {
   AA: 'jack' + '_sth', # How can I write like this: AA: basic.name + '_sth'
 },
};
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [reference variable in object literal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858931/reference-variable-in-object-literal)

Comment: You cannot have a comma before closing an object literal: `, }' is not allowed.

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

You have to do

```
var name = 'jack';

var person = {
 basic: {
   name: name,
   sex: 0
 },
 profile: {
   AA: name + '_sth'
 }
};
```

Just like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4858968/432354) says, you could also do something like the following

```
function Person() {
  this.basic = {
    name: 'jack',
    sex: 0
  };
  this.profile = {
    AA: this.basic.name + '_sth'
  };
}

var person = new Person();
```

But this creates an instance of `Person`, not a plain and simple JS object.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    var person = {
     basic: {
       name: 'jack',
       sex: 0
     }
   };
    person.profile= {
       AA:person.basic.name + '_sth'
    };
```

Comment: @pvorb initially I forgot to replace collon with equal.

Answer (score 0):

you just cant. other than work arounds like sushil's and pvorb's, you cant reference an object still being defined.

also you can try a getfunction

Answer (score 0):

You could also use an Immediately Invoked Function Expression ([IFFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)) :

```
var person = function(name) {
 var prsn = {
      basic: {
        name: name || 'anonymous',
        sex: 0
       }
      };
 return {basic: prsn.basic, profile: {AA: prsn.basic.name + '_sth'}};
}('Jack');
```