# Javascript handler reference to environment it was defined in

Tags: javascript, methods, this, handler

Is there a way for a javascript method to reference the environment in which it was defined as opposed to how it was called?  In this particular case - the method is defined in an *object literal*.

ie:

```
var obj = {
            init: function(){
                  jQuery("form").on('keyup','input',{self:this},this.checkDetails);
            }
            checkDetails: function(event){

                  console.log(this); 
                  // 'this' references the input object which invoked the method

                 console.log(event.data.self); 
                  //provides a correct reference to the object 'obj', but I had to pass it
            }

     }
```

`this` should reference the **generic** object in which it was defined.

Comment: Replace `console.log(event.data.self);` with `console.log(obj)`? Or are you looking for a more generic solution?

Comment: @merlin2011 This makes it necessary to let the value of the variable `obj` unchanged

Comment: I am looking for more generic solution

Comment: @dystroy - the method is defined in an object literal, which is not covered by the answer you indicated.

Comment: *" javascript method to reference the environment in which it was defined"*. An object literal isn't an environment. See also [this other related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858931/reference-variable-in-object-literal).